# Azure AD single sing on for Google Apps

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, idp

I am trying to establish AZURE AD as Identity provider of a Google workspace domain.

Provisioning goes smoothly.
When I try to implement SSO I have problems with the Claim transformations.

The AZURE domain is Ficticio.cat.com
The workspace domain is Xtecnologies.com

According to the Google documentation:
[https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on?hl=es-419#name:~:text=Los%](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on?hl=es-419#name:%7E:text=Los%) 20steps%20remaining,the%20next%20way%3A
I have established the Claim with domain substitution.

When trying to log in to gmail, it redirects me to the azure page but it does not recognize the Xtechnologies domain.

I have tried to do different transformations without success.
I change the user.principalname to the Xtechnologies domain, the federated devices do not allow login.